# When the nullity of the spanning subgraph is equal to a given value?

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory

Recently I was studying the lower coefficient of the graph polynomial:
\begin{equation}
     \sum_{A\subseteq E}(x-1)^{k\langle A\rangle-1}(x^{-1}-1)^{c\langle A\rangle}
 \end{equation}
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with vertex set and edge set. $\langle A\rangle$ is the subgraph whose edge set is $A$, vertex set is $V$ where $A\subseteq E$. k(G) is the number of components of the graph. c(G) is the cyclomatic number of the graph.
My idea is, to observe the property of the spanning subgraph by edge subset $A$ when $c\langle A\rangle$ is fixed. For example, for the coefficient of $x^{-c(G)+1}$, I only need to study the situation when $k\langle E-A\rangle=\lvert A\rvert$ and then expand the corresponding terms using its property. So, are there any papers on this subject that I can refer to? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please tell us about your designations: $E$, $k\langle A\rangle$, $c\langle A\rangle$, and others.

Comment: @kabenyuk Sorry, I have re-edited it.